# How to make a countdown timer function reusable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a countdown function like the following:

```js
data(){
    return {
        timer: null
    }
}

methods: {
    countdown: function(time){
        const TIME_COUNT = time;
        if (!this.timer) {
            this.count = TIME_COUNT;
            this.timer = setInterval(() => {
                if (this.count > 0 && this.count <= TIME_COUNT) {
                    this.count--;
                }
                else{
                    clearInterval(this.timer);
                    this.timer = null;
                }
        }, 1000);
}
```

I want to call the countdown function with different parameters like `countdown(10)` or `countdown(60)` so that every time I call this function it starts counting from the time I want. If I call the countdown method it will count to 0 before the second countdown works. What should I do to make it reusable?

Comment: can you clarify your question because i cant see what you want to do ? the method is working but what behavior do you expect ?

Comment: Please edit and click `[<>]` to make a snippet so we have a [mcve]

Comment: For example, I call the countdown with countdown (10) and countdown (60). If I skip the first countdown before it counts to 0, the second one is not starting from 60 but the remaining countdown (10)

Comment: The issue is the use of `this`. It represents your instantiated object. In your code, you use `if (!this.timer) {`. In other words: In case _myObject.timer_ is not set, create a counter. However, if one is set, do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should let you instantiate multiple countdown instance functions.

```js
const methods = {
  countdown: (time) => {
    let timeRemaining = time;
    let timer;
    timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (timeRemaining > 0) {
        timeRemaining--;
      } else {
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, 1000)
  }
}
```